# getting "User signal 1" that terminates my process, UNIX in C

Tags: c, unix, signals

```
void printToScreen(){
    write(1, boardString, strlen(boardString)) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;
    write(1, "\n", 1) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;

    int i = 0;
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok (boardString, ",");
    int len = strlen(pch);
    int count=0;
    // insert the number and pads it with zeros, '|' and spaces
    while (pch != NULL){
        printf("\niteration %d\n", count++);

        switch(len){
        case 1:
            if(*pch == '0'){
                write(1, "|      ", 7) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;
                break;
            }
            write(1, "| 000", 5) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;
            write(1, pch, 1) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;
            write(1, " ", 1) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;      
            break;
        case 2:
            write(1, "| 00", 4) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;
            write(1, pch, 2) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;
            write(1, " ", 1) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;  
            break;          
        case 3:
            write(1, "| 0", 3) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;
            write(1, pch, 3) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;
            write(1, " ", 1) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;  
            break;              
        case 4:
            write(1, "| ", 2) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;
            write(1, pch, 3) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;
            write(1, " ", 1) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;  
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        // update pch, len
        pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
        len = strlen(pch);
        i++;    
        // move to next line
        if (i % 4 == 0)
            write(1, "|\n", 2) == -1 ? writeError() : 1;    
    }
}

    void sig_hand(int sig){
    printf("got signal\n");
    read(STDIN, boardString, STRING_SIZE) == -1 ? readError() : 1;
    printToScreen();
}
```

I have this signal handler that handles SIGUSR1 signals.
 boardString is an array of 16 ints in string format, with ',' as delimiters. 
 The printToScreen() just prints it in a 4X4 matrix format 
I have a second process that sends SIGUSR1 to this process after each update in the boardString. 
 My problem is that the printToScreen function doesn't end. it prints the first iteration just fine and then I get this msg "User signal 1" and that's when my program terminates. 
 I can't understand why it terminates and what "User signal 1" means.

Comment: `pch = strtok (NULL, ",");` -> when is `pch` not going to be NULL here?

Comment: after the strtok will clear all the ',' from the string

Comment: I'm fairly certain the `strtok()` function is not considered async-signal-safe, and thus should probably not be called in a signal handler...

Comment: OK thx, I will look into it. Is there an alternative for this funcion? because I need to remove all ',' from this string I got

Comment: I have checked, and strtok isnt the problem :( , but thx anyway

Comment: This is just an incomplete fragment of code that will not compile and run as is, so we're forced to guess at the parts you didn't include.  Post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how to. It's a 3 prats code, 400 lines total. I don't really see how to cut the non-relevant parts, because I'm not sure where the problem is. Is there an option that I will upload the c files to here?

Answer (score 2):

From the description, it sounds like you're setting up the signal handler as a single-use handler (so it is called the first time the signal is received, and is then reset to the default action, which is to kill the process; the shell will then generally print the "User signal 1" message).

How are you setting the signal handler?  If you are using `signal` and are using a SysV-derived unix variant, the default will be single use.  Use `sigaction` instead, and make sure the `SA_RESETHAND` flags is *not* set.

Comment: In my code I first declare the signal handler and use this line "usr_action.sa_flags = 0;" so I think it should do what you just said, isn't it?

Comment: Additionally, I am using sigaction: sigaction (SIGUSR1, &usr_action, NULL);

Answer (score 1):

```
to start, there are other error return codes besides -1
and write() normally returns the number of chars written
and "\n" can be (depending on OS) more than one char
so the first two lines would be better written as:

(write(1, boardString, strlen(boardString)) < 0) ? writeError() : strlen(boardString);
(write(1, "\n", sizeof("\n") ) < 0) ? writeError() : sizeof("\n");

The follow is an example for handling a signal (note: kill and stop cannot be handled)
caveat: I have not run the following, so it may have keypunch errors.

#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

// handle the signal
void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGUSR1)  printToScreen();
}

// register the signal handler
typedef void sigfunc(int)

sigfunc* = signal(SIGUSR1, (sigfunc*)sig_handler(int));
```

Comment: You might want to proofread that, at a glance the code has more problems than just missing semicolons.